# Powershell Function Return Value is changed

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with functions in Powershell. I want to give back a int32-Value, but the Value & the Data-Type are always getting changed... I have no idea why.

Thats the main part, where the Functions get called..

```
$DocPath = "\\CHVMES02\Registry\EXCEL_ALLE\Version_AllFromExcel_Aktuell"
$server = "chvmes01"
$Building = "E44"
$AID = "N/A"
$Anlage = "Engineering"

$applicationPoolsPath = "/system.applicationHost/applicationPools"
$applicationPools = Get-WebConfiguration $applicationPoolsPath

foreach ($appPool in $applicationPools.Collection)
{
    #[int32]$CheckBoxNumber = 1

    $appPoolPath = "$applicationPoolsPath/add[@name='$($appPool.Name)']"


    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $True
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Add($DocPath + "\IIS Application Pool.dotm")
    $Selection = $Word.Selection

    $CheckBoxNumber = general

    $CheckBoxNumber = cpu

    processModel

    ProcessOrphaning
}
```

Now first the Function general is called:

```
Function general{
        #General Informations

        $General = Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool | Select *  
        $AppPool = $appPool.Name
        $Category = "General"

        $hash = @{
                    0x0 = $General.managedRuntimeVersion
                    0x1 = $General.enable32BitAppOnWin64
                    0x2 = $General.managedPipelineMode
                    0x3 = $General.queueLength
                    0x4 = $General.startMode
                    0x5 = $appPool

        }

        $columns = @{
                        0x0 = "CLR-Version"
                        0x1 = "Enable 32bit"
                        0x2 = "Managed Pipeline Mode"
                        0x3 = "Start Mode"
                        0x4 = "Queue Length"
                        0x5 = "Name"
        }

        $CheckBoxNumber = GenerateTable $hash $columns $AppPool $Server $Category

        $Type = $CheckBoxNumber.GetType()

        $CheckBoxNumber
}
```

From Inside the function General i call the Function "GenerateTable", which as the Name says already, generates the table and fills in the Data...

```
Function GenerateTable{
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
            [HashTable]$hash,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)]
            [HashTable]$Columns,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=3)]
            [string]$AppPool,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=4)]
            [string]$Server,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=5)]
            [string]$Category
        )

        $Range = @($Selection.Paragraphs)[-1].Range
        $a = $Selection.MoveDown(5, 1000)

        $RowsCount = $hash.Count +1

        $Table = $Selection.Tables.add(
        $Selection.Range,($RowsCount),2,
        [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior]::wdWord9TableBehavior,
        [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior]::wdAutoFitFixed)

        $tblTitle = $AppPool + ": " + $Category + ", Server: " + $Server + " - " + "Datasource: IIS Manager"

        $Table.Cell(1,1).Merge($Table.Cell(1,2))
        $Table.cell(1,1).range.Bold=1
        $Table.cell(1,1).range.text = $tblTitle

        $ColNr = 2
        foreach ($h in $Columns.GetEnumerator() | Sort Key) {
            $Value = $h.value

            $Table.cell($ColNr,1).range.text = $Value
            $ColNr = $ColNr+1
        }

        $ColNr = 2

        foreach ($x in $Hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort Key) {
            $Value = [string]$x.value

            if(([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Value))){
                $Value = "N/A"
            }

            if($Value -eq $false -or $Value -eq $true){

                $Range = $Table.cell($ColNr,2).range
                $Document.FormFields.Add($Range, 71) 
                $CheckBox = "Check" + $CheckBoxNumber 
                $Type = $CheckBoxNumber.GetType()
                $CheckBoxNumber = $CheckBoxNumber + 1 
                $Type = $CheckBoxNumber.GetType()

                if($Value -eq $true){
                    $Document.FormFields($Checkbox).Checkbox.Value = True
                }
                Elseif($Value -eq $false){
                    $Document.FormFields($Checkbox).Checkbox.Value = False
                }
            }
            Else {
                $Table.cell($ColNr,2).range.text = [string]$Value
            }

            $ColNr = $ColNr+1
        }

        $a = $Selection.MoveDown(5, 1000)
        $Selection.Text = "`n`n"      

        $CheckBoxNumber

}
```

I have the Variable "$CheckBoxNumber", which I always increment by 1 every Time a Checkbox is inserted..
To fill in all the Data, we have the different functions: general, cpu, processModel...
To process the Checkboxes correctly, i need to pass the incremented $CheckBoxNumber-Variable to the next function.

From the first function "general" i call the function "GenerateTable", in the end of "GenerateTable", the Variable has the Value of 2 and is a "int32". Thats all correct.

Now the first part of the Problem: I give the Value back to the general-function, the $CheckBoxNumber-Variable suddenly changed to Type "Object[]", the Value is still 2.

But when we get back the the main-part, from where the second function CPU is startet, the Value also changed back to 1....

I have no idea why! Am I giving the parameters back to the functions in the wrong way?? I Also tried with return, but it also didnt work... I also tried to convert the value with [int32], but then i get the "Cannot Convert..." failure.. Can somebody help me with this weird problem??

Comment: Some methods return output and any output will be returned to the pipeline, so it's likely some action you perform in your function is returning an output (such as $true) and then you are also returning $CheckBoxNumber. As such the result ends up being two outputs, which becomes an `Object[]` because it is a collection of objects (the two results). At a guess, I would say look at the `$Document.FormFields.Add($Range, 71)` line. If it is this line (or one similar), you can fix by adding `| out-null` to the end, which will ensure the undesired result doesn't get returned to the pipeline.

Comment: This line could also be returning some result: `$Table.Cell(1,1).Merge($Table.Cell(1,2))`. One way to run the code up until this line and see if any output you don't expect is returned.